# No margin on DataMatrix barcodes generated by ZXing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, zxing

I tried to have no margin for DataMatrix barcodes, but it doesn't seem to be working, whatever number I put, it's still the same default margin. Any idea please?

```
NSError * error = nil;
ZXMultiFormatWriter * writer = [ZXMultiFormatWriter writer];
ZXEncodeHints * hints = [ZXEncodeHints hints];
hints.margin = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];
ZXBitMatrix * result = [writer encode:barcodeString
                              format:kBarcodeFormatDataMatrix
                               width:30
                               height:30
                                hints:hints
                               error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is because the library cannot adjust the size. If a barcode has 10 rows, then it must be a multiple of 10 pixels for the size.

If putting 12 pixels, there's gonna be a margin of 1 on each side to compensate.